# Where exactly to use ngCloak in existing app

Tags: angularjs, ngcloak

We have an AngularJS app (not a SPA). We face this problem where some part of uncompiled template is displayed for brief moments, so I am applying ngCloak directive to the app.

I'm not sure of where exactly should this directive be used - every single, small element or large sections (or somewhere else). What I'm currently doing is throttling connection via Chrome dev tools to a very slow speed and then checking which parts of template show up in raw state. But I feel this is not a very deterministic approach.

So I would like to know the where exactly to use ngCloak.

Thank You.

Comment: you probably should preffer [ng-bind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) over `{{ }}` so ng-cloak isn't needed.

Comment: @AntiHeadshot we already use ngBind and no `{{ }}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying ngCloak to every small element is certainly the wrong way to go.

You would typically want to apply it either to large sections, or to the entire portion of your page that uses Angular. The objective is to hide these parts of the page until Angular is ready to use.

This is what the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) says:

> The directive can be applied to the `<body>` element, but the preferred usage is to apply multiple ngCloak directives to small portions of the page to permit progressive rendering of the browser view.

If you don't want your users to be looking at blank space, you can show a loading animation until Angular finishes loading. You can do this by giving the element an `ng-show="false"` directive:

```
<img src='/images/loading.gif' ng-show='false' />
```

Comment: Are there are performance implications of extensive use of ngCloak?

Comment: @HarshilSharma ngCloak works by having a CSS rule hide things on the page until Angular is done loading. So it may have some effect on performance if you use it a ton, but probably not much. Best way to find out is to try it and see.

Answer (score 1):

Please add following code into head section of index.html

```
<style>
    [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

And you can add same code into your css file

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without [ng-cloak] when you run your application before angularJs rendering you will see some angular codes like "{{myngModel}} or something like this, when you put [ng-cloak] in your project on run you didn't see those codes until rendering complete .

```css
[ng\:cloak],
[ng-cloak],
[data-ng-cloak],
[x-ng-cloak],
.ng-cloak,
.x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <title>app</title>
</head>

<body ng-cloak>
</body>

</html>
```